# Table as an enum. Is it possible?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, enums

How can I a map static table (which is not expandable) to an enum in Java and bind this table to another one?

For example, I have simple calculator web app (spring web MVC + hibernate) with one table (results of user's calculations) which has the following fields: `id (PK)`, `leftOperand`, `operation`, `rightOperand`, `result`.

I would like to create a new static table (I mean for basic arithmetic operations like `PLUS`, `MINUS`, `DIVIDE`, `MULTIPLY`) with 2 fields: `id(PK`) and `operation`, and map this table to enum in Java.

So how can I bind these two tables (using `operation` field)?
Some pseudo-code is greatly appreciated.

Note that I do not need to create a hibernate entity for the static table. Just enum.

Comment: so you will have an Enum in Java with the id to String mapping, yet you also want to persist the exact same info in the database?! and hence have duplication. makes no sense (to me) why you would want to do that. Somebody may come in and update the Java enum mapping in the meantime and then they are inconsistent ...

Answer (score 1):

As with classes, you can add properties to enums like so:

```
public enum MyEnum {
    PLUS(1, "something"),
    MINUS(2, "something");

    private final int id;
    private final String string;

    private MyEnum(int id, String string){
        this.id = id;
        this.string = string;
    }

    public int getId(){
        return id;
    }

    public String getString(){
        return string;
    }

}
```

Assuming the 'opreration' field matches the enum's `name`, you can do the following:

```
MyEnum enumValue = MyEnum.valueOf(map.get("operation"));
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't need static table for operation values. Just change `operation` field type to enum and use `@Enumerated`.

```
enum Operation {
    PLUS, MINUS;
}

@Entity
public class Calculation {

    private String leftOperand;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Operation operation;

    private String rightOperand;

}
```

Comment: Yes that is straightforward. But is there any way to have a separate table which is maped to enum and bind to main table ?

Comment: @stryker I don't think that there is a way to do it. Having separate static table for enum doesn't seem to have any sense.

Comment: there are 2 reasons: map table to enum and bind these tables to each other, That is not real web application. It's just for test and I would like to know how it works. Thanks

Comment: We have a requirement to back all enums with tables for the team members who want to do everything in SQL...